# Objective C how to use caching to upload images and videos to server faster

Tags: objective-c, image, caching, video

Everytime I ask how I can improve upload time on a video or image to my server, everyone always says to use cache. I'm not sure how I can use caching to upload videos and images faster? Can someone give me an example maybe? Thank you

Comment: This isn't a clear question;  what have you tried?  What have you investigated (what did Google say)?   Off the cuff, "use a cache" isn't going to make a network connection any faster itself.   So, what, exactly, is slow?

Comment: What's slow is when I try to upload a video that the user recorded that is usually about 1 MB, it is also slow when I try to retrieve such videos as well (from the server). I want to make this faster if I possibly can.